# Unit testing a print method

Tags: java

How to create a class that add some stuff to a map and display it.

I was wondering about the best interface considering that all the code usually need to be covered with unit tests and it's a problem to test a method that display data.

This was my first thought:

```
class MyFirstProgram {
    private Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    public int insertData(...) {...}
    public void displayData(...) {...}
}
```

...but it's not possible to test anything about the retrieval and there is this display method... so I thougt this:

```
class MyFirstProgram {
    private Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    public int insertData(...) {...}
    private Map<String, String> retrieveData(...) {...}
    public int displayData(...) {...call ; return status}
}
```

In this it's possible to test the private method with reflection but there is still this display method...

Any idea about the design?

Comment: you want to add some data to the map and retrieve it to display. right?

Comment: You could mock whatever is displaying the data and make sure the input received by the mock is what you expect.

Comment: I think that returning just the map and printing outside would be wrong for 2 reasons:

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating getter and setter for the Map variable.

```
class MyFirstProgram {
    private Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    public setMap(Map data) {...}
    public Map getMap(...) {...}
}
```

And then wherever you want to print the map value use getMap method.
If you don't want to use the setters and getters we can have any method which takes a Map as input and print it.

```
public void PrintMap(Map data){print(data)}
```

Comment: I think that returning the map and printing it outside would be wrong for 2 reasons:
- What's printed is not the exact object, but may be quite different and probably a lot of logic need to be added, depending on the parameters.
- It would bring the logic of the class outside, violating the encapsulations.

Comment: See my answer, but what I do is expose the Map via a package method with the comment // for unit tests.  Yes, you are breaking encapsulation but in a limited way and with an explanation.

Comment: To access any private data getter and setters are the best possible way. But if you dont like calling the map from outside you can use any method to print the data.

Answer (score 0):

The pragmatic way is to allow access to the Map (via a default/package access method with a comment `// for unit tests`, and access that.  Actually, even better, name the method `forUnitTestGetMap()` to make it extra clear and avoid confusion with the standard getXXX naming convention.  I'm usually fine with just calling `toString()` on the Map and comparing to what it should be, YMMV.  If your `insertData()` is just calling standard methods on HashMap (e.g. put()) there isn't that much you *can and should* test, as most of the code is Java library code.

Alternatively, in the `displayData()` method, does it create an alternative representation of the Data?  Such as XML, JSON, maybe a JPanel?  If so, look at that to see that the contents of the Data are correct.  Obviously XML is much easier than a JPanel for that, but you can still do something like checking that the JPanel has 3 children and the first is a Button named "OK"...

Comment: The displaydata in my example would show some additional information to the data contained in the map, by making calculation. Or it could skip some items, depending on some criteria. Now I was thinking would be fine to generate an hashcode of the string to be printed. The same string may be written manually in the unit test, where should generate the same hashcode.

Comment: I like comparing the toString()s, not the hashcodes, because then the failure message is much more informative.